# -Wlogical-op-parentheses analog in rustc

Tags: rust

C++ compilers have an option to warn against writing `a || b && c` without parentheses (clang and gcc do this automatically on -Wall, the specific option in clang is called [-Wlogical-op-parentheses](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wlogical-op-parentheses)). Is there an analogous feature in rustc?

Comment: I don't want to answer saying that such a lint does not exist (since I have not exhaustively confirmed this), however I could not find any analogous lints in the compiler's allow-by-default list nor in clippy's list. It might just be the case that no one has thought to add that lint yet.